# Create WSO2 Custom User Store Listener

Tags: wso2, listener, customization

Custom user store listener not getting invoked.

Followed the documentation on how to create custom user store listener.

How to register the event listener
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Writing+a+Custom+Password+Validator

User Store listener
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/User+Store+Listeners

A Sample Code of custom listener
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/user-mgt/custom-listener/

Event Listeners
 
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
            org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.store.JDBCIdentityDataStore

```
    <!-- Enable this listener to call DeleteEventRecorders. -->
    <EventListener type="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener"
                   name="org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.listeners.UserDeletionEventListener"
                   orderId="98" enable="false"/>
    <EventListener type="org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
                   name="org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.consent.ConsentMgtPostAuthnHandler"
                   orderId="110" enable="true"/>
```

```
    <!-- Audit Loggers -->

    <!-- Old Audit Logger -->
    <EventListener type="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener"
                   name="org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.listeners.UserMgtAuditLogger"
                   orderId="0" enable="false"/>

    <!-- New Audit Loggers-->
    <EventListener type="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener"
                   name="org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.listeners.UserManagementAuditLogger"
                   orderId="1" enable="true"/>
    <EventListener type="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserManagementErrorEventListener"
                   name="org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.listeners.UserMgtFailureAuditLogger"
                   orderId="0" enable="true"/>

    <!-- OS Custom event handler-->
    <EventListener type="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener"
                   name="org.wso2.carbon.sample.user.operation.event.listener.SampleUserOperationEventListener"
                   orderId="49" enable="true"/>
</EventListeners>
```

Here is the SampleUserOperationEventListener code.

public class SampleUserOperationEventListener extends AbstractUserOperationEventListener {

```
//private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SampleUserOperationEventListener.class);

private static final Log audit = CarbonConstants.AUDIT_LOG;
private static String AUDIT_MESSAGE = "Initiator : %s | Action : %s | Target : %s ";

@Override
public int getExecutionOrderId() {

    //This listener should execute before the IdentityMgtEventListener
    //Hence the number should be < 1357 (Execution order ID of IdentityMgtEventListener)
    return 49;
}
```

I am expecting it will call the custom listener and log the information when a user activity happens in WSO2 admin console and also when user logs into the service provider.

I did not find any where this listener getting called by WSO2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you deployed this custom listener as a OSGI bundle. If this bundle successfully activated it should get called when user creation request is made. You don't need to add it under EventListners adding to dropins folder will do the job. First of all check whether bundle is activated by OSGI console.

Steps:

1. start the wso2 identity server with -DosgiConsole

> ./wso2server.sh -DosginConsole

2. After server starts up enter the following command.

> ss soasecurity

3 That will give a bundle id with the artifact name of the bundle.

> b {bundle id}

This will give the status of the bundle whether it is activated or not. If it is not activated. There are few reasons to happen so.

1. carbon kernel version used in IS-5.6.0 is 4.4.32. But in your listener you have used 4.2.0.
2. Check your bundle manifest file for correct import package and export package details

Please refer this blog and its references for more information

https://medium.com/@inthiraj1994/user-operation-event-listener-for-wso2-server-8ce4765b8c95

Please let me know if you are still having this issue.

Comment: I could able to get it up and running and check the OSGi bundle is active state. 
The logging was still not happening. After using slf4j in the POM file and refactoring logger, I can see the custom log in audit file now.  
-pom changes
**<dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>**
-logger used in java code
**private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleUserOperationEventListener.class)**

Comment: Now I need to print the Client IP address in the audit logs. Is there APIs to access the Client IP listener.

Comment: There is no such API to get that. But you can have that using log4j configurations. There is no such API to get that. But you can have that using log4j configurations. You need to add the following configuration to

{IS-HOME}/repository/conf/log4j.properties .  
**log4j.appender.CARBON_SAMPLE.layout.ConversionPattern=TID: tenant id: [%T] server name :[%S] host name/address: [%H] instance id: [%I] application name: [%A] [%d] %P%5p {%c} - %x %m %n**